# Register different configurations of the same bean

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

Using Spring 5 on Java 9....

Not even sure this is possible.  Have a very simple class:

```
public class Exchange {
  @Autowired
  private OtherService other;

  @JmsListener(destination = {some.queue})
  @Transactional
  public void receive(String payload) {
    other.send(payload)
  }
}
```

Both `Exchange` and `OtherService` just needs a couple of configuration properties (i.e. **some.queue**) to work.  Would like to register (either through `BeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessor` or `ApplicationContextInitializer`) multiple instances of the `Exchange` bean but with prefixed configuration properties.  Anyway to alter attribute definition when registering a bean?

Comment: have a look at this one: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49423156/1970670

Answer (score 1):

I think you want a combination of two things, `@ConfigurationProperties` and `@Qualifier`.

[`ConfigurationProperties`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-external-config-validation) let's you supply a `prefix` that applies to all of the `@Value` properties loaded injected in tho that class.

[`@Qualifier`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#beans-autowired-annotation-qualifiers) allows you to specify which one of potentially many valid `@Autowire` targets you'd like. Specify the bean name and you are set.

Quick untested example:

```
@Component("FooExchange")
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "foo")
class FooExchange implements Exchange {
    @Value("enabled") private boolean enabled;
    ...
}

@Component("BarExchange")
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "bar")
class BarExchange implements Exchange {
    @Value("enabled") private boolean enabled;
    ...
}
```

And the properties you'd define are:

```
foo.enabled = true
bar.enabled = true
```

And when you inject one:

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier("FooExchange")
private Exchange myInjectedExchange; // Which will get FooExchange
```

Edit: You may beed to annotate one of your configuration classes or your main class with `@EnableConfigurationProperties` to enable the configuration properties.

Comment: Wasn't aware that ConfigurationProperties pushed over a prefix to Value attributes.  Cool.   Still wonder if it would be possible to register a bean but alter say the prefixes when registering?  Don't need to inject (i.e. with Qualifier) the Exchange just have instances with different configuration.