# Multiple immutable properties in Spring Boot with @ConfigurationProperties and @ConstructorBinding

Tags: java, spring-boot

We have an application that houses a bunch of very similar cron-scheduled jobs. They all use `@Scheduled` annotation and have a couple of fields in common, like `limit` and `timeout`.

Mentioning `@Scheduled` parameters here might be useless, but they get to be mentioned the [metadata](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/configuration-metadata.html) on compile, so having extra unused fields is worth. A bit clearer documentation is always a plus.

```java
@Data
class JobProperties {
    private String cron;
    private String fixedDelay;
    private String fixedRate;
    private String initialDelay;
    private int limit;
    @DurationUnit(ChronoUnit.MINUTES)
    private Duration timeout;
}
```

I want to take an approach of sharing the dto between the job configurations from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58973426/7643283):

```java
@Configuration
public class JobConfiguration {
    // Lies in other file, listed just for the clarity
    private static final String OUR_PREFIX = "com.xobotun.github.example";
    
    @Bean
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = OUR_PREFIX + '.' + Job1.techName)
    public JobProperties job1Config() {
        return new JobProperties();
    }  
    
    @Bean
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = OUR_PREFIX + '.' + Job2.techName)
    public JobProperties job2Config() {
        return new JobProperties();
    }
    
    // Repeat a couple more times
}
```

But I also want to make this dto immutable. Nobody sane would write into the properties file, but accidents may happen. Better to prevent stuff like this on the compiler's level. So I want to declare all fields as `final`, and declare these properties injectable not through setters, but via constructor using `@ConstructorBinding`, like in the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57191291/7643283). Maybe through `@AllArgsConstructor(onConstructor_ = @ConstructorBinding)`.

However, my problem is that this annotation is actually processed by [ConfigurationPropertiesBindConstructorProvider](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/f97d5af46726553b3952873d566d1282b2f2d174/spring-boot-project/spring-boot/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/context/properties/ConfigurationPropertiesBindConstructorProvider.java#L68), and I create instances myself in my `JobConfiguration` class.

➥ Has anyone encountered this issue? Only thing I found is [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61725677/7643283), but it was asked a year and eight months ago, and haven't received any sensible answers, sadly.

I'll go with the mutable dto by now, but I'll be eager to see if there is any way to spring-bootize these into the code. Maybe through some factories, I don't know. :D

Comment: The only solution I can come up with is by subclassing `JobProperties`, putting the `@ConfigurationProperties` on each subclass, and loading the subclasses with `@EnableConfigurationProperties`. This is also covered in the duplicate question.